# All Super Bowl Champions

Tags: json, freebase, mql

I'm trying to get all champions of the Super Bowl.
I used the [Query Editor](http://www.freebase.com/queryeditor/) and wrote this code:

```
[{
  id: "/en/super_bowl"
  "/sports/sports_championship_event/champion" : [{}]
}]​
```

But everything I get is this:

```
{
  "code":          "/api/status/ok",
  "result": [{
    "/sports/sports_championship_event/champion": [],
    "id":            "/en/super_bowl"
  }],
  "status":        "200 OK",
  "transaction_id": "cache;cache02.p01.sjc1:8201;2013-01-21T20:27:29Z;0064"
}
```

Can anybody help me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go to the topic page for [/en/super_bowl](http://dev.freebase.com/en/super_bowl) you'll see that the Super Bowl is a [Sports League Championship](http://dev.freebase.com/sports/sports_championship?schema) which is composed of individual [Sports League Championship Events](http://dev.freebase.com/sports/sports_championship_event?schema) (eg. [Super Bowl XLVI](http://dev.freebase.com/m/043t_rh)).

Your query is asking for all the champions of the Super Bowl when what you need to be querying for are the champions of each of the individual Super Bowl Championship Events in Freebase. That query looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "/en/super_bowl",
  "/sports/sports_championship/events": [{
    "/sports/sports_championship_event/champion": [{}]
  }]
}​
```

You can adapt this query to get the winning team and the year like this:

```
{
  "id": "/en/super_bowl",
  "/sports/sports_championship/events": [{
    "name": null,
    "season": {
      "/time/event/start_date": null
    },
    "/sports/sports_championship_event/champion": [{
      "id":   null,
      "name": null
    }]
  }]
}​
```

Go Niners!